# Cannot override EclipseLink batch fetch type through orm.xml

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have a class A with one to many relation to class B. It looks like this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "B_A_ID", referencedColumnName = "A_ID", 
insertable = false, updatable = false)
private List<B> bElements;
```

I need to change the batch fetch type of this property to EXISTS or IN because of [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=387574) EclipseLink bug, but I don't have acceess to the source code of class, so instead of @BatchFetchType annotation I decided to do it through my orm.xml file.

```
<entity class="somepackage.A">
    <attributes>
        <one-to-many name="bElements" fetch="LAZY">
            <join-column name="B_A_ID" referenced-column-name="A_ID" insertable="false" updatable="false"/>
            <cascade>
                <cascade-refresh/>
            </cascade>
            <batch-fetch type="EXISTS"/>
        </one-to-many>
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

The problem is it does not work. I can change other properties of mapping, eg. fetch type to EAGER, but when I try to change the batch fetch type to EXISTS or IN, it seems to be ignored. What can be the cause of this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I've guess that you use JPA orm.xlm instead of EclipseLink orm.xlm

Please check your xmlns patch, it should be http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm
not
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm